# How to move left div to center while right div removed/commented?

Tags: html, css

I have following code and I want to move left div to center automatically while right div is not there.

```
<div class="main-content" style="width: 100%;">

  <div class="left" style="float:left; width: 70%;">
     <p>Left DIV Contents here..</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right" style="float:left; width: 30%;">
    <p>Right DIV Contents here..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aonly-child) or [`:only-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aonly-of-type) pseudo classes to target the `.left` DIV element which is the **only child** or **only type** of elements in its parent.

In addition, in order to override the inline styles, you could use `!important` keyword within the declarations:

```css
div.left:only-child { /* or :only-of-type */
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/mojaweni/2/edit)**.

It's worth noting that [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aonly-child) or [`:only-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aonly-of-type) pseudo classes [are supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aonly-of-type#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't mind switching up your markup to have your elements float from the right, you could use the adjacent sibling selector to achieve the effect you are looking for:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-content" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="right">
    <p>Right DIV Contents here..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
     <p>Left DIV Contents here..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-content{width:100%}
.right{float:right; width:30%}
.left{text-align:center}

.right + .left{text-align:left; float:right; width:70%}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mE75k/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:table-cell`

```
.main-content{
   display:table  
}
.left{
  width:70%;
  background:brown;
  display:table-cell
}
.right{
  width: 30%;
  background:green;
  display:table-cell
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kawefola/3/)**

Comment: This is good, but it does not exactly center `.left` when `.right` is gone.